# Declaration and Definition Separation for C++ Templates

Tags: c++, templates, header-files, template-meta-programming

So lately I have been making progress on building a personal library using Template Metaprogramming (using the book *Modern C++ Design* as my current reference).

I have been thinking about the best way to layout my template code. Obviously, the compiler wants the definitions of the template visible in the same file it is declared. However, I want to separate the declaration from the definition so I have less to look at when I just want to see a method prototype or something.

So to solve this, what I have been starting to do can be illustrated by the following example:

**SomeClass.hpp**

```
#ifndef _someclass_hpp
#define _someclass_hpp

template<typename T>
class SomeClass {
public:
...
private:
...
};

#include "SomeClass_Implementation.hpp"

#endif
```

**SomeClass_Implementation.hpp**

```
#ifndef _someclass_impl_hpp
#define _someclass_impl_hpp

#include "SomeClass.hpp"

/* SomeClass Implementation... */

#endif
```

I personally like this more than having everything in one file, but I am curious if anyone has any tips on approaching this or any reasoning that might make me consider just dumping it all into one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach I like is to do this:

Header.hpp:

```
#ifndef FileGuard_whatever // technically reserved by STL because
#define FileGuard_whatever // it starts with a capital letter

template <typename T>
class A
{
    void go ( T const& value ) ;
} ;

#include "Header.hxx" // implementation details

#endif // FileGuard
```

Header.hxx:

```
template <typename T>
void A<T>::go ( T const& value ) { }
```

Which is pretty much exactly what you do. I omit the addition File Guard in the other file and give a name letting people know not to import it.

I've had good luck with this. It takes people a sec to figure it out, but the `.hxx` helps at least a bit with that ("It's different; ok, *how* is it different?")

Comment: I like the idea of making the implementation header file with a slightly different extension. It's subtle but, like you said, it helps show it is different than the definition header. I also wasn't even aware there was a .hxx extension until your example! I will wait to see any other responses and see if there's any other interesting approaches.